# Tagging AWS Elasticache Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

Does anyone know a way to add tags to an Elasticache node like you're able to do with EC2 and RDS instances?

- Is this not an feature?
- If possible it available in either the console, command line tools, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it is currently possible (Jan 2015) either via the console, or the lastest version of the CLI (1.7.4).

This would be a nice feature to have, especially since we use tagging for cost allocation.

Comment: Thanks, seems to confirm the suspicions of everyone I've been speaking to.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging support for Elasticache clusters and snapshots was launched in Feb 2015 : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tagging-for-elasticache-clusters-snapshots/.

Hope this helps!